# Removing logback `INFO` messages from Maven Console for junit tests

Tags: java, junit, maven-3, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

I have placed a `logback.xml` in `src/test/resources` from my maven project. My intention is to have a separate logback config for my tests and actual code. `My logback.xml` looks like below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern> 
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <!-- Daily rollover -->
      <fileNamePattern>/tmp/SolrUpdaterTest.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
      <!-- Keep 7 days' worth of history -->
      <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

While doing `mvn test` my maven console is cluttered with lot of  logback INFO messages as shown below even though I have set root error level to `ERROR`

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.jabong.discovery.importer.solrUpdater.document.attributes.AttributesFastTestSuite
13:02:58,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
13:02:58,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
13:02:58,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/home/jabong/code/github.com/jabong/voodoo/solrUpdater/target/test-classes/logback.xml]
13:02:58,180 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
13:02:58,180 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/home/jabong/code/github.com/jabong/voodoo/solrUpdater/target/classes/logback.xml]
13:02:58,180 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/home/jabong/code/github.com/jabong/voodoo/solrUpdater/target/test-classes/logback.xml]
13:02:58,264 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
13:02:58,269 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
13:02:58,278 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [CONSOLE]
13:02:58,301 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
13:02:58,355 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
13:02:58,357 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
13:02:58,375 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
13:02:58,377 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern /tmp/SolrUpdaterTest.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log for the active file
13:02:58,382 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/tmp/SolrUpdaterTest.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log'.
13:02:58,382 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
13:02:58,385 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Thu Dec 10 13:02:58 IST 2015
13:02:58,387 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
13:02:58,388 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: /tmp/SolrUpdaterTest.2015-12-10.log
13:02:58,388 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [null]
13:02:58,390 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to ERROR
13:02:58,390 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [CONSOLE] to Logger[ROOT]
13:02:58,391 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
13:02:58,391 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
13:02:58,392 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@dc24521 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
```

My pom.xml looks like below:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.jabong.discovery.importer</groupId>
    <artifactId>solrUpdater</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>solrUpdater</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <runSuite>**/AttributesFastTestSuite.class</runSuite>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.jabong.discovery.external-repos</id>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.arnabk</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-dogstatsd-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>Updater</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
                <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>one-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${runSuite}</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
            <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Can some let me know how can I disable the logback `INFO` in maven console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should name the file logback-test.xml for testing

Logback uses this file if exists on path prior to logback.xml

In your case, you have no logback-test.xml but 2 files logback.xml on path, so it uses no configuration to force you fix the problem

Comment: This is one of those things that I just always took for granted myself. Thanks for the answer. For others reading, here's some [documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html) on the subject.